# Gradle project sync fails

Tags: java, android

I get this error:

> Gradle project sync failed

I don't understand how to use the levels that the other users said and unfortunately  didn't get my problem solved. I'm a beginner.

Comment: Can you please describe the error description or stack race ?

Comment: without a detailed error message this question is impossible to answer. please add some more information or you'll have this put "on hold" with high probability. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)